# indexOfPath incorrect in a nested NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have a nested `NSArray`

```
int row = [myarray indexOfObject:module];
```

and the `indexOfObject` method returns wrong result. Any idea?

Comment: What result do you expect and what result do you get?

Comment: Not without seeing the array and more code.

Comment: What are you storing in the array and does that object correctly implement the `isEqual` and `hash` methods.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the object `module` or one of the objects in the `NSArray` do not implement the `isEqual:` method correctly. Make sure that `module`'s class has this method

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject {
    ...
}
```

and the method returns `YES` when this object is equal to `anObject`, and returns `NO` otherwise.